# change python version 2.7.3 to 2.7.9 (anaconda)

Tags: linux, python-2.7, ubuntu, pybrain

The default version of python in my linux dist is python 2.7.3, but I usually use spyder for coding which uses 2.7.9. I want to install the PyBrain module so that I can use it in Spyder, so I downloaded the source code. if I run python setup.py install, it will install it in 2.7.3.

I tried using ln -s:

ln -s /opt/python/bin/python2.7.3 /usr/local/bin/python2.7.9

This didn't work because 2.7.9 is not in /usr/local/bin/ , in fact, I have no idea where python 2.7.9 is. I looked around in my folders and I can't find it.

Thank you

Comment: `whereis python` gets the location of the binary files you need.

Comment: It shows python 2.7 but not 2.7.9

Comment: Do you have 2.7.9? How did you install it in the first place?